# PHP How to pass an instance of the class in the function of another class?

Tags: php, class

index.php

```
include('./class1.php');
include('./class2.php');

$Func = new function_test();
$Func->testfuncton1();
```

class1.php

```
class controller{

  public function test2(){
    echo 'this is test';
  }
}
```

class2.php

```
class function_test{

  public $string_row;

  public function __construct() {
   $this->string_row = 'TEST code';
  }

  public function testfuncton1(){
    controller::test2();
  }
}
```

We would like print value `$string_row` in function `test2()` in class `controller`, but we don't know how to do it...

Tell me please how to pass an instance of the class in the function of another class ?

P.S.: we have element `$string_row` in class `function_test`. we would like show his value in function `test2()` (in class `controller`).

Comment: Give meaningful names to your classes/methods: `test1`, `test2`will drive you mad. Plus, class names should always begin with capital letter.

Comment: That's not an element (`$string_row`) but an instance variable and you can't have instance variables in classes but only in instance of classes. And functions of classes are called methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I addded some additional methods to show all possibilities:

```
class controller{
  //normal methods, must be called on instances of controller    

  //pass a object of type function_test
  public function testObject($object){
    echo $object->string_row;
  }

  //pass a string 
  public function testString($string){
    echo $string;
  }

  //static method, can be called on the class itself
  public static function staticTest($string){
    echo $string;
  }
}
```

Now call the methods:

```
class function_test{

  public $string_row;

  public function __construct() {
   $this->string_row = 'TEST code';
  }

  public function testfuncton1(){
    (new controller())->testObject($this);
    //or
    (new controller())->testString($this->string_row);
    //or call the static one
    controller::staticTest($this->string_row);
  }
}
```

It should be: `$this->string_row`
And I would highly recommend to read a good book about object orientated programming.

Answer (score 0):

Ok things you got wrong:
- `$this->$string_row = 'TEST code';` should be `$this->string_row = 'TEST code';`
- Also as pointed out earlier it is better to call `regular functions` using `objects` instead of `classes`

So, `controller::test2();` is better written as

```
$cn = new controller();
$cn->test2();
```

I think from a design perspective it is better to instantiate an object of function_test in class controller and use it instead of passing it around.

```
class controller{

  public function test2(){
    echo 'this is test';
     //since we call the constructor of function_test,
     //this will assign value to string_row
    $ft = new function_test();

    // since string_row is a public property, 
    // you can directly echo it.
    echo $ft->string_row;
  }
}
```